# a function to adjust spacing between paragraph to fill the div height

Tags: javascript, height, line

What I have is a div with some items (menu item), this div will be the height of the browser viewer and I would like the spacing between the `<p>` to fill the height of the div.

So for a 1024px screen sixe, 20 px spacing is fine between paragraph, but sometimes it better to be 17px and for some big screen, 22 px should be fine.

Do you have a javascript function to auto calculate this or a jQuery plugin ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd at least show a snippet of HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a newish css module called flexbox. check [this](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=column&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=flex-start&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) out. 
basically set the container height to 100%, and set the elements each to `flex:1 1 auto`.
play around with that URL too

more info:
here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaLZW/). it's rudimentary but demonstrates the basic idea. just set the height of `.flex-container` to `100%` when you put it in on your page. (i have the fiddle set to `400px` because `100%` doesn't grab the result-frame height in a jsfiddle.)
the CSS looks daunting because a lot has to be vendor-prefixed but it's actually quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to modify the margin of p tags based on height of parent div - maybe something like this would help

```
MAX = 200;
if ($('div').height() > MAX) {
  $('p').attr('style', 'margin:10px 0 10px 0;')
} else {
  $('p').attr('style', 'margin:0 0 0 0;')
}
```

Comment: i think "spacing between the `<p>`" implies that line height is not the issue - changing line height would change the height of every line *inside* the `<p>`

Comment: ahh maybe i should edit answer so that height of p tag is changed.

Comment: right ... it's the margin not the line-height... margin between <p>